# Find/get online the title for urls in text file and save to the same file

Tags: powershell

I would like to get/find online the titles from text file with URLs.
The structure of file is:

```
11/23/2018 17:03:46;$https://www.seznam.cz
11/23/2018 17:10:12;$https://www.centrum.cz
```

Can you help me with the new structure of text file with the title from that URL as the third column?

```
11/23/2018 17:03:46;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznam etc.
```

My Code which does not work:

```
$url = get-content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\titles.txt $result =
Invoke-webrequest -Uri $url -Method Get $resultTable = @{}
$resultTable.title = $result.ParsedHtml.title Write-Output New-Object
-TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $resultTable
```

Comment: The code you posted is broken b/c of bad formatting. Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the code from your script.

Comment: @niekas Re-formatting broken code into a different kind of broken is not helpful. Please don't do that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry, my mistake. Just wanted to increase readability.

Comment: @niekas That's appreciated, but when we neither know what the actual code looks like nor what about it actually isn't working, that doesn't help the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks really funny because of the `$` signs in there, I think the easiest method is to treat it as CSV and go from there:

```
$inputFile  = 'D:\urls.txt'
$outputFile = 'D:\urls-with-titles.txt'

# Read the headerless textfile and replace all `;$` into a single ';'
# so we can use ConvertFrom-Csv.
# Collect the output for each delimited output string in a variable
$result = (Get-Content -Path $inputFile) -replace ';\$', ';' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header date, url | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # put the url and date in variables so we can use them inside the catch block if needed
        $url  = $_.url
        $date = $_.date
        try {
            $page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.url -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop
            # output a string, delimited by ';$' 
            '{0};${1};${2}' -f $_.date, $_.url, $page.ParsedHtml.title
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "An error occurred on Url '$url'.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
            # output the line with the title empty
            '{0};${1};$' -f $date, $url
        }
    }

# show output on screen
$result

# write output to a new headerless text file
$result | Set-Content $outputFile -Force
```

Result:

> ```
> 11/23/2018 17:03:46;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
> 11/23/2018 17:10:12;$https://www.centrum.cz;$Centrum.cz
> ```

<sup>Note: I'm using a different file name for the output text file so as not to destroy the original.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Theo. But the code ends with error (404):

Invoke-webrequest : Vzdálený server vrátil chybu: (404) Nenalezeno.
At line:10 char:17
+         $page = Invoke-webrequest -Uri $_.url -Method Get
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Can you help me? What´s wrong?

Comment: @PetrSoren The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. One of the urls in the textfile may no longer be valid. I have edited my answer to cope with that using a `try{..} catch{..}` construct.

Comment: Of course, the "same" error (404) writes now:
WARNING: An error occurred on Url 'https://www.denik.cz/rodina/pet-tibetanu-krok-za-krokem-cvicte-je-kazdy-den-a-nemusite-do-po
silovny-20180529.html?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp'.
Vzdálený server vrátil chybu: (404) Nenalezeno.

The code interrupts and doesn´t go on. It´s a problem. How can I set to continue of powershell script?

Comment: How can I skip no existing web-sites in this code?
For example:
https://www.denik.cz/rodina/pet-tibetanu-krok-za-krokem-cvicte-je-kazdy-den-a-nemusite-do-posilovny-20180529.html?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp;utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu

Comment: And it´s very slow, i have got 6000 rows in text file.

Comment: The updated code does not exit. Did you try? And yes.. Probing websites is slow.

Comment: Aha, ok, the script goes on after error 404. Thank you very much, Mr. Theo. I tried it now on a little text file with bad url and it works.

Comment: I have got a question. How can I delete the no existing/wrong web sites in script? When "catch" finds no title, can I delete the whole row with wrong url? Thank You.

Comment: @PetrSoren Yes, If you delete or comment out the line `'{0};${1};$' -f $date, $url`, inside the `catch{..}` block, the bad url will not be written out. P.S. Perhaps it is a good idea to splite the source file with 6000 lines into a series of smaller batches. Then change the `Set-Content` cmdlet into `Add-Content`, so all will write to the same file.

Comment: Ok, good idea with spliting file, but there is my problem again, that script is not working with some rows in my big text file, for example with these rows is script KO.
2018-11-24 21:11:00;$https://atlas.centrum.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:52;$https://www.kafe.cz/krasa-a-zdravi/priznaky-starnuti-ktere-se-plizi-pomalu-ale-jiste-20190211.html?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp;utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu

Comment: @PetrSoren That site has many redirects and that causes the problem. Was trying to tackle this in the code, but I see you already posted it as new question. [LotPings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57097571/9898643) fixed it for us.