# Invoke-WebRequest - script doesn´t work as expected

Tags: powershell

> I have PowerShell script (from Mr. Theo) for get titles from urls in
>   big text file (6000 rows). My problem is that some rows in text file
>   with urls are specific and script doesn´t work. Script is not ending.
>   The structure of files is (input.txt):

```
2018-11-23 17:10:20;$https://www.super.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz
2018-11-25 11:20:23;$https://www.kara.cz/muzi
2018-11-26 21:11:00;$https://atlas.centrum.cz (problem row)
2018-11-27 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz
```

> Desired structure of file is:

```
2018-11-23 17:10:20;$https://www.super.cz;$Super.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
2018-11-25 11:20:23;$https://www.kara.cz/muzi;$Kara - Online obchod Kara
2018-11-27 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
```

> Or other desired structure:

```
2018-11-23 17:10:20;$https://www.super.cz;$Super.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
2018-11-25 11:20:23;$https://www.kara.cz/muzi;$Kara - Online obchod Kara
2018-11-26 21:11:00;$https://atlas.centrum.cz;$ (problem row without title)
2018-11-27 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$Seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
```

> Can I export the wrong rows or delete them? Can You help me how to update the script?

```
$inputFile  = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\OSTROTA\input.txt'
$outputFile = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\OSTROTA\urls_title.txt'

# Read the headerless textfile and replace all `;$` into a single ';'
# so we can use ConvertFrom-Csv.
# Collect the output for each delimited output string in a variable
$result = (Get-Content -Path $inputFile) -replace ';\$', ';' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header date, url | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # put the url and date in variables so we can use them inside the catch block if needed
        $url  = $_.url
        $date = $_.date
        try {
            $page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.url -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop
            # output a string, delimited by ';$' 
            '{0};${1};${2}' -f $_.date, $_.url, $page.ParsedHtml.title
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "An error occurred on Url '$url'.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
            # output the line with the title empty
            '{0};${1};$' -f $date, $url
        }
    }

# show output on screen
$result

# write output to a new headerless text file
$result | Set-Content $outputFile -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script uses

- `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')` for current users Desktop,
- [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to better define parameters,
- `Invoke-WebRequest` with the parameters `-Timeoutsec=1`,`-MaximumRedirection=1` to speed up getting the title and avoid a possible redirection loop.
- has an alternative output format with a PSCustomObject, ATM commented out.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\07\18\SO_57093988.ps1
$Desktop    = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$inputFile  = Join-Path $Desktop 'OSTROTA\input.txt'
$outputFile = Join-Path $Desktop 'OSTROTA\urls_title.txt'

$result = (Get-Content -Path $inputFile) | ForEach-Object {
    $date,$url,$title = $_ -split ';\$'
    try {
        $params = @{
            Uri                = $url
            Method             = 'Get'
            ErrorAction        = 'Stop'
            Timeoutsec         = 1
            MaximumRedirection = 1
        }
        $title = (Invoke-WebRequest @params).ParsedHtml.title
        if(-not $title){$title = (([System.Uri]$url) -Split '\.')[-2]+' - najdu tam, co neznám'}
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "An error occurred on Url '$url'.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        # output the line with the title empty
        $title = ' (problem row without title)'
    }
    '{0};${1};${2}' -f $date,$url,$title
    # Alternatively use a PSCustomObject
    #[PSCustomObject]@{
    #    date = $date
    #    url  = '$'+$url
    #    title= if($title){'$'+$title}
    #}
}

# show output on screen
$result

# write output to a new headerless text file
# $result | Set-Content $outputFile -Force
```

Sample output of both variants (German locale):

```
> Q:\Test\2019\07\18\SO_57093988.ps1
WARNUNG: An error occurred on Url 'https://atlas.centrum.cz'.
Es wurden zu viele automatische Umleitungen versucht.

date                url                       title
----                ---                       -----
2018-11-23 17:10:20 $https://www.super.cz     $Super.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:34 $https://www.seznam.cz    $seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
2018-11-25 11:20:23 $https://www.kara.cz/muzi $Kara - Online obchod Kara - Muži
2018-11-26 21:11:00 $https://atlas.centrum.cz $ (problem row without title)
2018-11-27 21:09:34 $https://www.seznam.cz    $seznam - najdu tam, co neznám

> Q:\Test\2019\07\18\SO_57093988.ps1
WARNUNG: An error occurred on Url 'https://atlas.centrum.cz'.
Es wurden zu viele automatische Umleitungen versucht.
2018-11-23 17:10:20;$https://www.super.cz;$Super.cz
2018-11-24 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
2018-11-25 11:20:23;$https://www.kara.cz/muzi;$Kara - Online obchod Kara - Muži
2018-11-26 21:11:00;$https://atlas.centrum.cz;$ (problem row without title)
2018-11-27 21:09:34;$https://www.seznam.cz;$seznam - najdu tam, co neznám
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify that line in `catch { ... }`:

```bsh
'{0};${1};$' -f $date, $url
```

If you don't want it to appear at all, just comment:

```bsh
#'{0};${1};$' -f $date, $url
```

If you want to add custom message, you should add it after `$url` and also add `${2}`:

```bsh
'{0};${1};${2}' -f $date, $url, ' (problem row without title)'
```

As [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) mentioned in comments, some websites might require `-UseBasicParsing` parameter for [`Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6), otherwise they'd hang.

In that case, `ParsedHtml` property will be blank, so you need to find another way to extract a title. One example using regular expression:

```bsh
try {
    $page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.url -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop -UseBasicParsing
    $title = ($page.Content -match "<title>(.*)</title>")[0]| % {$Matches[1]}
    # output a string, delimited by ';$' 
    '{0};${1};${2}' -f $_.date, $_.url, $title
}
```

In that case you search for `<title>Something something</title>` and extract `Something something` from it using capturing group. While whole match is saved to `$Matches[0]`, you don't need that so you use next element from `$Matches` array, which matches your capturing group.

---

**Explanation**: `catch { ... }` block is being used as you specifically told the script to enter it in case any errors: `-ErrorAction Stop`. That parameter forces any errors to trigger `catch { ... }` block. In that case error is

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not in catch but in script. When did you try add rows in text file, for example input.txt with problematic row, or only this row, also:
2018-11-26 21:11:00;$https://atlas.centrum.cz   ... and run the script, it doesn´t work (id doesn´t stop, it runs all the time) without export result. I must it stop manually.

Comment: If you want to clarify something, please add it to the question, do not use comments.

Comment: @PetrSoren I created the input.txt file based on the example you provided and my script gave me the exact result you specified in your question - not sure what else to do to improve the answer

Comment: @robdy Problem seems to be that the site `https://atlas.centrum.cz` does return quickly with `-usebasicparsing`, but without it seems to hang.The text `(problem row)` is only a note and shouldn't be part of the url.

Comment: @LotPings ok then, I don't have this issue on my environment, so that's why I had some issues to understand what's the problem. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Yes, (problem row) and (problem row without title) are only notes, there aren´t in text file. When I set -Method Post, it´s better but with big text file is problem with error 405 on web sites, this row is problematic too: 2018-11-24 21:09:51;$www.seznam.cz/r/https%253A%252F%252Fwww.kafe.cz%252Fkrasa-a-zdravi%252Fpriznaky-starnuti-ktere-se-plizi-pomalu-ale-jiste-20190211.html/j2T9MlDjPrdV32l3RSB4tQ?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp

Comment: With this url script doesn´t work:
2018-11-24 21:09:52;$https://www.kafe.cz/krasa-a-zdravi/priznaky-starnuti-ktere-se-plizi-pomalu-ale-jiste-20190211.html?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp;utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu


The script has got problem with this url. How can the script continue? No error in catch..

Comment: @PetrSoren add `-UseBasicParsing` as LotPings suggested (I added such info to my answer too).

Comment: Where can I add -UseBasicParsing?

Comment: Read my answer once again, please :)

Comment: When I add this -UseBasicParsing parameter to script, nothing is finding... (all rows are signed "problem with row" including correct´s rows)

Comment: You're right, I added the example of how you could address that. It doesn't cover all the cases but should work as a starting point.